# Why don't both Supply and Demand Curve Shift in Loanable Funds Market in Case of Gov't Deficit/Surplus?

Tags: macroeconomics, supply-and-demand, interest-rate

[Here](https://www.khanacademy.org/economics-finance-domain/macroeconomics/monetary-system-topic/macro-the-market-for-loanable-funds/a/the-market-for-loanable-funds) it is written:

> But that doesn’t mean both curves shift? Supply and demand do not have the same determinants in any market. Your graphical model should reflect only one point of view.

I don't understand why both curves don't shift and also, I don't get what this means. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks